# Excel formula to calculate date based on 2 cells and how to copy to other cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

Novice excel user here. Here is a simplified version of my spreadsheet:

```
start date  end date    eday    duration
                        -21     4
                         12     0

begindate = "03/03/2020"
```

I want to create formulas to calculate start date and end date based on values in eday and duration columns and begindate:

```
start date = begindate + eday
end date = start date + duration
```

So for the above example if I apply a formula, I would expect the following result:

```
start date  end date    eday    duration
02/11/2020  02/11/2020  -21     4
03/15/2020  03/19/2020   12     0
```

begindate `03/03/2020` will always be the same.

I was able to get a formula working but when I use the fill handle it doesn't copy the formula correctly.

Please help a novice with these questions:

1. Where is the best place to store the begindate "03/03/2020" - a separate worksheet? hardcode it? other?
2. What is the formula for start date and end date?
3. How do I copy the formula into all rows in the column

Thank you very much.

Comment: What formula did you try to copy, and how did it end up in the other cells?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I like to remember about dates and times in Excel, is that they are really only numbers, which are formatted to look like dates/times using number formatting.  Today's date (07-Sep-2019) is 43715, and the current time (12:20AM) is 0.14302083...

There are worksheet functions that can get the magic number (essentially days since 01-Jan-1900) for you, such as `DATE()`, `TODAY()` or `NOW()`.

To that end, assuming your *eday* column is `C` and your data starts in row `2`, you can enter your *start date* formula in `A2` as `=DATE(2020,3,3)+$C2` and your *end date* formula in `B2` as `=$A2+$D2`.  That is the simplest approach.

Note that I have used absolute column references (`$C`, `$A`, `$D`) to force Excel to always look in columns `C`, `A` and `D`, regardless of where I copy/paste or fill, and I have used relative row references (`2`) so that, if I copy/paste or fill down, the row number will change as part of the filling (i.e. on row `3`, the formula would read `=$A3+$D3`).  Sometimes you want this, sometimes you don't, so you should experiment with `$` and no `$` to see what it does.

I suspect that you originally put your *begin date* value in a cell, but used a relative reference in your formula and, when you filled down, the relative reference for your *begin date* changed.  If I'm right, then you would need an absolute reference for your *begin date* cell, e.g. if it was in column `J` row `1`, your formula should read `$J$1`, not `J1`.

As you get more confident, you can use more-complicated features to make this more resilient or configurable.  For instance:

- You can use the *Name Manager* to store your fixed, constant date, by creating a new name called `BeginDate` and setting its value to `=DATE(2020,3,3)`.  Now you can update your start-date formula in `A2` to be `=BeginDate+$C2` and that fixed value will be used everywhere.
- You can format your four-column range as a *Table with Headers*, which will allow you to use those header names instead of column references.  If you format the range as a table, then in the first data row of your *start date* column (which was `A2`) you can enter `=BeginDate+[eday]` and in your *end date* column (which was `B2`) you can enter `=[start date]+[duration]`.  Because it is a table, both formulae should fill down automatically, as the table grows.  Now apply a simple number format of *Short Date* to your *start date* and *end date* columns.
- You can stop your table showing calculated dates when you haven't entered any values for `eday` or `duration` by changing your formula in *start date* to the more-complicated:

  ```
  =IF([eday]="", "", BeginDate+[eday])
  ```

  ...and changing the formula in *end date* to:

  ```
  =IF(OR([start date]="",[duration]=""), "", [start date]+[duration])
  ```